# How to translating Excel formula to Python/Pseudo code

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pseudocode, nested-if

I am trying to translate an Excel formula for column `CB` into pseudo code that I can then add to my Python script. I have reviewed the [structured reference documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/using-structured-references-with-excel-tables-f5ed2452-2337-4f71-bed3-c8ae6d2b276e?ocmsassetID=HA010155686&CorrelationId=42c5f4a1-b24d-447c-ad1f-6eea907950eb&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#BMstructured_reference_syntax_rules) for Excel, but there is still something I am not getting.

```
 =IF(CA2="NO",IF(OR(I2="X", I2="D", I2="V",I2="VE",I2="0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD", 
I2="AREA NOT INCLUDED"), "UnMapped",IF(LEFT(R2,3)="NON","UnMod","Modernized")),IF(OR(BJ2="X", 
BJ2="D", BJ2="V",BJ2="VE",BJ2="0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD", BJ2="AREA NOT INCLUDED"),
"UnMapped",IF(LEFT(BK2,3)="NON","UnMod","Modernized")))
```

I am getting stuck on what to do with `"UnMapped"` after the first `IF(OR...)` statement. Here's my Pseudocode so far:

```
IF CA = "NO":
    IF (I2="X" OR I2="V" OR I2="V" OR I2="VE" OR I2="0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD" OR I2="AREA NOT INCLUDED"):

      IF (LEFT(R2,3)="NON" OR LEFT(R2,3)="NON" OR LEFT(R2,3)="Modernized"):

    ELSE IF (BJ2="X" OR BJ2="V" OR BJ2="V" OR BJ2="VE" OR BJ2="0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD" OR BJ2="AREA NOT INCLUDED"): 

      IF (LEFT(BK2,3)="NON" OR LEFT(BK2,3)="UnMod" OR LEFT(BK2,3)="Modernized"):
```

Where should the "UnMapped" go?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this may be what you are looking for:

```
if CA2=="NO":
    if (I2=="X" OR I2=="V" OR I2=="V" OR I2=="VE" OR I2=="0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD" OR I2=="AREA NOT INCLUDED"):
        return "UnMapped"
    elif (LEFT(R2,3)=="NON"):
        return "UnMod"
    else:
        return "Modernized"
elif(BJ2=="X" OR BJ2=="V" OR BJ2=="V" OR BJ2=="VE" OR BJ2=="0.2 PCT ANNUAL CHANCE FLOOD HAZARD" OR BJ2=="AREA NOT INCLUDED"):
    return "UnMapped"
elif(LEFT(BK2,3)=="NON"):
    return "UnMod"
else:
    return "Modernized"
```